# Make the type of one property depending upon other properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Basically a function can take either of these two types or param:

`{a: string, b: number, c: SomeType}`
`{a: string, b: number, d: SomeOtherType}`

I know I can write the type of the parameter as `{a: string, b: number, c: SomeType} | {a: string, b: number, d: SomeOtherType}`, but I'm trying to come up with something like:

`{a: string, b: number} & ({c: SomeType} | {d: SomeOtherType})`

So that I don't have to repeat the first two properties, is this possible?

Comment: Just define some `Base` type like [here](https://tsplay.dev/w65JRW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a type alias for the static properties and then use the [intersection operator (`&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to combine them with the optional [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjA8mZB7AdgZygF4oBvAWACgop4AuKPYAJyRwHMBuS6gI3pwCuAWx4QmXCgF8JlUJCgZs+IrATJ0mJLgIAyKAApupKCno8sWADYR4OKJKgAfYwBN+Ay5fuUAlDIoAZgI4KEpQAXb6WJra9Ipa+D70AG5YSC6kkpRAA)

```ts
type StaticOptions = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
};

type Options = StaticOptions & (
  { c: boolean } | { d: null }
);

function fn (options: Options): void {}
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086570/make-the-type-of-one-property-depending-upon-other-properties/72086638#comment127370539_72086638):

You can define the exclusive properties as [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and `never` in each other's shape for "easier" DX:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjA8mZB7AdgZygF4oBvAWACgop4AuKPYAJyRwHMBuS6gI3pwCuAWx4QmXCgF8JlUJCgZs+IrATJ0mJLgIAyKAApupI9RT0eWLABsI8HBOrUAJgH5+EAG5iHUSUYA+xlSOKG5QOJ7eJlBO-AJWVj5+FACUMhQAZgI4KEpQGTgGWJra9Ipa+Cn0HlhITkGm2sANjvAANFAA9J0MzKxs0Twd3eHCokzRKMM9Fta2hYHZThAZrBBO0U7TowlQizjLqxEbwZIqxUp4EslAA)

```ts
type StaticOptions = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
};

type Options = StaticOptions & (
  {
    c: boolean;
    d?: never;
  }
  | {
    c?: never;
    d: null;
  }
);

function fn (options: Options): void {
  const {
    a, // string
    b, // number
    c, // boolean | undefined
    d, // null | undefined
  } = options;
}
```

Comment: I got confused because now typescript won't let me do `const { a, b, c, d } = options`, but I guess that makes sense, since either c or d won't be present in options.  The message Typescript was throwing saying neither c nor d were defined is what was throwing me off. 

Thanks!

Comment: @RubenSerrate See update